# Laravel 5 : the move() function doesn't save the uploaded image file

Tags: php, laravel-5

What I'm trying is to set an image uploader with Laravel 5.

Here is the form.

```
    <form action="/edit/{{$id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            //There are other tags (including other input) here
            <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
        <input type="submit" value="Apply Changes">
    </form>
```

Here is the controller function which will be run from the `form` above.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $this->model->find($id)->fill($this->request->all())->save();
    if ($this->request->hasFile('pic')) {
        $file = $this->request->file('pic');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('assets/serviceimages/', $name);
    }

    return redirect('/blahblah');
}
```

As you might have noticed, this doesn't store the uploaded file under the `assets/serviceimages/` directory, which is what I've been trying.

Basically I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/04/08/processing-file-uploads-with-laravel-5/), but apparently I'm missing something and totally clueless about what it is, even after I had a look at the [API documentation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L172).

Inside of the `if` statement of the controller function, it was confirmed that the `$file` and `$name` had what I expected.

Therefore, I suspect that the problem lies in the `move()` function.

Any small piece of advice will be appreciated, since this is my first time that I've tried to set an uploader.

Comment: Does the path actually exist and does it have the right permissions? Your path it's currently trying to save to is `/public/assets/serviceimages/`. Other than that have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions if you are on Linux. If that doesn't work try it this way:

```
$image = $request->file('pic');
$destinationPathImg = '/your path/images/';

if (!$image->move($destinationPathImg, $image->getClientOriginalName())) {
    return 'Error saving the file.';
}
```

Also, this need to be added in ur ()

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: Just FYI, you are basically replicating what Laravel does within the `move()` method. If it can't move then it would throw an exception

Comment: Yea, i know. I have this code tested and its working so i just copied it, thats why i suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

I found having to use the Storage adapter to use the full file path worked for me.

```
$storageAdapter = Storage::disk('v1')->getDriver()->getAdapter()

$full_path_before = $storageAdapter->applyPathPrefix($oldPath);
$full_path_after = $storageAdapter->applyPathPrefix($newPath);

if (!File::exists($full_path_before)){
   throw new \Exception("Error moving folders");
}
$move_files = $full_path_after !== $full_path_before;

if ($move_files){
   File::move($full_path_before, $full_path_after);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Method This Will Work 100%

```
if($request->hasFile('filename')){

     $file = $request->filename;

    $file_new_name =  $file->move("upload/posts/", $file->getClientOriginalName());

    $post->filename = $file_new_names;

   }
```

> Remember filename is your < img name="filename" >